# how many days it would take to complete the work for the first time working in alternate days given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If A can complete a wall in 21 days and B can destroy a wall in 28 days. Then how many days it would take to complete the work for the first time working in alternate days i.e, if A works one day then second day in a week B will work?

My Approach:

Work Done by A in 1 day = 1/21

Work Done by B in 1 day = -1/28

Net work done  together in 2 days = 1/21 - 1/28 = 1/84

In one day = 1/168

> Q Is my approach right.Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Almost. Note that what you've calculated is on what day, after $B$ is done demolishing, there is still a complete wall left. That is not the same as _the first time_ $A$ completes a wall.

Comment: @Arthur How do we know there is still a complete wall left?

Comment: Because that's how you've set up your solutions. You check on the second day, and see that $1/84$ of the wall is done. You therefore conclude that after $168$ days, the work is done. And you come there the $168$th day, and there stands a full wall. But $B$ has done his demolishing that day, which means there were more than a full wall there after the $167$th day.

Comment: This is the [frog-in-a-well](http://www.bhavinionline.com/2015/06/how-many-days-does-it-take-the-frog-to-escape-from-the-well/) problem.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your analysis, 
$$\frac 1{84}\cdot m+\frac 1{21}=1\\
m=80$$

Number of days required to complete the wall is given by
$$2m+1=161$$